# Printing Crystal Report from Motorola MC 3000

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, compact-framework, windows-ce, motorola

Is it possible to print a Crystal Report report from MC 3000 (Motorola) using wireless?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/218e7296-a6f4-48a1-9dc2-5bb3cda8e004/support-for-crystal-report-tool-in-net-compact-framework?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs

I don't think that this is possible. Mobile Applications usually don't have the task to create and print reports. Try it with a service on a server who receives the necessary data and redirects it to a report and then to a printer.